# Webservices Server-Client, RabbitMQ

Tags: web-services, apache-flex, rabbitmq

Dear Masters in stackoverflow,

I want to build an app,
Spring-WS on server side, and Flex on client side.
And I'm going to put RabbitMQ in the middle.

I have gone through the tutorials in RabbitMQ.
And I've read Spring-AMQP.

My question is:
1. Is it neccessary for Flex as client to also implement RabbitMQ?
2. If it's neccessary, how to implement FLex Webservices with RabbitMQ?
3. How about Apache Servicemix? Is it neccessary for client to also install/implement Servicemix?

I will be so thankful for the answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

RabbitMQ is a messaging broker that provides an infrastructure for fast messages communication.

You should use it if you want some real-time communication between your nodes.

If you consider using RabbitMQ with Flex, then I have created a Flex/ActionScript library for AMQP 0.9.1 protocol (latest RabbitMQ):
https://github.com/mexxik/strymqp-as
There under flex-demo folder you can find simple examples on how to use the library. If you have any question regarding that, I will provide more detailed tutorial.

But in general, if you just want to retrieve data from Spring in Flex you could use simple remoting (remoting is not that easy withj RabbitMQ) with BlazeDS.
Also, you could consider creating RESTful web services on the server-side. The good option would be Spring MVC, and consume them on the Flex side.